# Pass default image to Sitecore MVC Field helper

Tags: sitecore

Anyone know how I can specify the default editor image that shows when rendering a sitecore Image field?

```
 @Html.Sitecore().Field("Image", new { @class = "full" })
```

In Page Editor, before the author as set the image, I get the ugly default sitecore image. I want to specify my own for different cases. Is there a way to pass the default image to use the Field helper?

Answer (score 0):

The default image is defined on the following item in the core database, which you can change.

[image]

Alternatively, you can subclass Sitecore's default image rendered (`Sitecore.Xml.Xsl.ImageRenderer`), and override the `GetDefaultImage()` method.

---

Another less fragile solution is to place an Edit Frame around the image. This allows you to retain the Page Editor functionality that you get from `@Html.Sitecore().Field()` helper.

This example assumes the use of the Glass Mapper, however, you should be able to adapt it to use the default SitecoreHelper.

```
@using (Html.BeginEditFrame(Model.Id, new ID(Constants.ItemIDs.EditFrameButtons.Image)))
{
    if (Model.Image != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Image.Src))
    {
        // Render image here
    }
    else
    {
        <img src="//placehold.it/400x225/2379cf/fff" alt="placeholder_image" />
    }
}
```